# How to resize content to automatically fill entire screen space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have looked for answers, and find ways of adjusting the size of the container to fit to the size of the content, but what I want is to adjust the content to fit the screen.

For example, this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A little bit of preamble before the form.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Is incredibly simple. I want to access the same site from different screens, a desktop, a phone, etc.

Is there some code that will adjust the font of the text, adjust everything so that it takes up the entire window? Or at least something that when double clicked from a phone, zooms in automatically. On a phone, you have to two-finger pinch zoom. But on most websites usually double clicking an area automatically zooms into the maximum possible size. This code doesn't even allow for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'm interpreting this correctly, but this piece of code will make it so that things look normal on smaller resolutions and not like the desktop screen if you put it between the opening `<html>` and `<body>` tags:

```html
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```